# Does anyone know of the following quote from Rabbi Yerucham Levovitz?

Tags: sources-mekorot, food, bathroom, miracle

I am looking for the source on the quote from Rabbi Yerucham Levovitz: "“If a person would know what happens to the food from the moment they put it into their mouth to the moment it leaves their body, just to study that process they would see as one of the greatest miracles of life and they would dance every single time they go to the bathroom.”

Comment: Where did you hear this quote? Might help those looking for its source

Comment: I can't remember. I have it written down somewhere and don't know the source. Perhaps it is from a video class because I tried many searches in both English and Hebrew and nothing showed up.

Answer (score 6):

Rav Matisyuha Solomon quotes a similar episode he heard from Reb Leib Gurwitz about Rav Yeruchem.

In response to a maskil that made fun of Torah Jews as "Asher Yotzar people", as if they do nothing but say the Asher Yotzar  all day. Rav Yeruchem responded with a long talk about the potential danger involved in bathroom use. He ended by saying that if after traveling a person sends a message that the trip went well, he would do the same after bathroom use if would realize the danger he was just saved from. He ended by saying, that they call us "Asher yotzar people", I wish we would  be befitting of such a title.

I heard this [or something very similar to this] from Rav Elya Svei Zt"l in the name Rav Yeruchem as well.

[image: Sefer v'Gar Ze'ev - Rav Matisyahu's hesped qouting this, part 1]
[image: Sefer v'Gar Ze'ev - Rav Matisyahu's hesped qouting this, part 2]